# How to start animation in synchronous style in styled-components

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I have the following code

```
:first-child {
transition: all 0.2s linear;
      transform: ${({ open }) =>
        open
          ? '  translateY(7.5px) rotate(45deg)'
          : '  rotate(0deg) translateY(0px)'};
    }
```

How can I make sure translateY finishes completely before doing the rotate transform?

Comment: how do these codes work now ?

Comment: They work at the same time, when what I want is for the translate to finish completely before rotation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way to achieve what you need is using css [keyframes](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes) :

```js
import { css, keyframes } from 'styled-components';

const openKeyframe = keyframes`
  50% {
    transform: translateY(7.5px) rotate(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(7.5px) rotate(45deg);
  }
`;

const openAnimation = css`
  animation: 1s linear ${openKeyframe} forwards;
`;

const Component = styled.div`
  :first-child {
    ${({ open }) => open && openAnimation}
  }
`;
```

`forwards` keyword will keep your component at the end state of the animation when it's finished, which I suppose is what you're looking for if you need to keep an `open` state.

Comment: This makes alot of sense, and If I understood it right, Ill need to create another keyFrame for close. Thank you